# How to easily access a group of nodes in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have a single role that has slightly different nodes in it. I usually do the following tasks/main.yml:

```
- include: spark_master.yml
  when: spark_master|default(false)|bool

- include: spark_worker.yml
  when: spark_worker|default(false)|bool
```

And than in inventory file:

```
[spark]
192.168.172.101 spark_master=true spark_worker=false
192.168.172.102 spark_master=false spark_worker=true
192.168.172.103 spark_master=false spark_worker=true
```

However, if I need to access all of the workers in a template in some other role I do not have a good way of doing that.

I was thinking about having actual host group entries instead and that way I can reference workers like this:

iventory:

```
[spark-workers]
node1
node2
```

template in other role:

```
{{ groups['spark-workers'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_eth0', 'ipv4', 'address']) }}
```

Is there a better way of accessing a subgroup of nodes without actually using different groups in the inventory file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, as my answer contradicts with "no separate groups" requirement, but have you considered using [children groups?](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#groups-of-groups-and-group-variables)

So in your case you'll have a

```
[spark:children]
spark-master
spark-workers
[spark-master]
192.168.172.101
[spark-workers]
192.168.172.102
192.168.172.103
```

and then you can reference `groups['spark-workers']` and `groups['spark']` as you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advocate that splitting your inventory groups into `spark-workers` and `spark-masters` would be the cleanest route.  But if you're dead set on your current inventory here's how you can reference other groupvars/hostvars in an Ansible template.

```
{% for host in groups['spark'] %}
{% if hostvars[host].spark_master|bool %}
# do some spark master stuff
{{ hostvars[host].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
{% else %}
#do spark worker stuff
{{ hostvars[host].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It's important to note that accessing the default facts of a host in this manner only works if the hosts are in the playbook.  Meaning that this template would fail if you are running a playbook against a group `foo`  since none of the facts from the group `spark` have been gathered.

To get around this you can create a dummy play before your real play to gather facts from `spark`.

```
- hosts: spark
  tasks:
  - debug:
    msg: "This is to gather facts from spark"

- hosts: foo
  tasks:
  - name: create template
    template:
      src: template.j2
      dest: /some/path/template
```